# how to update the /etc/hosts files in pods when ever new pod is created

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, updates, hosts

I use a bash script to update the `/etc/hosts` file of a pod with static hostname and default IP of other pods. when ever pod restarts or manually forced to delete. the new pod created will not have the updated `/etc/hosts` file? how to handle this

Comment: why do you need to update it?

Answer (score 1):

Do absolutely nothing; don't even try to manage `/etc/hosts` files.  Docker [provides internal DNS resolution between containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) ([Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has a clearer description) so you can generally use other containers' `--name` as host names directly.

If you're using `docker run` commands you need to manually `docker network create` a network (to create a "user-defined bridge" for the first link).

```sh
# Create a non-default network
docker network create some_network

# Run a server on that network
docker run -d --net some_network --name server nginx

# On the same network; uses the other container's name
# "server" as a host name
docker run --rm --net some_network \
  busybox \
  wget -O- http://server
```

If you're running this under Docker Compose, it does all of this setup for you (again, see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/); the Compose default network is named `default` but is not "the default bridge").  If you're running in another cluster environment (Kubernetes, Nomad) it will have its own similar DNS resolution system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hostAliases in pod template to add static host entries in pods /etc/hosts file, you can check here [Adding host entries in pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/)